# Symfony ~ SULU - Property from "route" to "resource_locator"

Tags: sulu

In the exemple i made in the pictures, i change the property "url" of "Mathématique" page type from "route" type to "resource_locator" but this one is skipped in the hierarchy usage.

Do you have any idea about how to refresh URLs ?

```
<property name="url" type="resource_locator" mandatory="true">
    <meta>
        <title lang="en">Resourcelocator</title>
        <title lang="de">Adresse</title>
    </meta>

    <tag name="sulu.rlp"/>
</property>
```

[image: Hierarchy]

[image: Add new page]

Comment: I would recreate the page. Seems like something maybe wrong with that page after you changed the route type.

Comment: I tried to recreate the page, but i can no more use the slug 'under-mathematique-page' in the path. It will be under-mathematique-page-1

Comment: You first need to rename the old pages url and remove the old pages url from its url history.

Comment: I juste tried it, i change the old page to "/mathematiques-1" instead of "/mathematiques" and remove the url history, and when i try to add new page with "/mathematiques" i got "mathematiques-2" with message "Error - The URL "/college/5eme/mathematiques" is already assigned to another page.
"